# How to I undo .detach()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using JQuery 1.5 and the following code to detach li elements w/ a certain class when a button is clicked.  What I want to know is, when that button is clicked again, how do I add the element back onto the page?

```
    <script>
    $("#remove").click(function () {
      $('li.type').fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).detach(); });
    });</script>
```

Comment: This is a good question, however, your lack of acceptance is disturbing. People who might know are not as forgiving as I am. Please accept some answers before asking new questions. :) (no bad feelings however)

Comment: Why detaching it and not just hiding it? Otherwise you have to keep a reference to the element.

Comment: @Felix, I'm using nth-of-type(odd) and (even) in my style sheet to position elements differently.  When I use .hide the odd/even status of the hidden element is retained, messing up the placement of everything else.  .detach fixes this, but I don't know how to bring the element back in this way.

Comment: @felix, .remove() fixes my style issue as well, but I figured I'd have better luck getting .detach to come back.  Maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is: ***where*** on the page do you want to put the element back? If, for example, all the `li` elements go back inside `<ul id="foo"></ul>` you might use something like this:

```
var items = [];
$('li.type').fadeOut(300, function() {
     items.push( $(this).detach() );
});

$('#replace').click(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        $("ul#foo").append(items[i]);
    }
    items = [];
});
```

Comment: That's the trouble.  It's an ordered list.  I'm trying to put elements of a class back into their original positions in the list.

Comment: The next question then, is: can I click `remove` more than once? That is, first remove one set of elements, then another? Or are only one set of elements ever removed at a time?

Comment: Okay, so... In my mind there were, say, 5 buttons, all that removed list items of 5 distinct classes.  When clicked again, those buttons would bring their respective list items back onto the page, but in their original order.  I'm no good at JavaScript, so maybe I'm overthinking... essentially I'm just building a filterable list based on assigned classes as opposed to actual list content.

Comment: The basic problem is that while you can easily do `parent = detached.parent();` and then later `detached.insertAfter(parent);`, essentially remembering where the element's parent was, that will fail if the parent also happens to get removed. A cleaner approach in this case is probably to just go through the list each time you re-insert an element and "figure out" where it belongs based on content (rather than trying to remember what the DOM has looked like during any number of changes).

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.  And this is actually for a timeline that uses the HTML5 time element, so doing it that way shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

here u can't for loop.

```
var demo;
$('li.type').fadeOut(300, function() {
     demo = $(this).detach();
});

$('#replace').click(function() {
   $("ul#foo").append(demo);
});
```