# how to get the information removed with detach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, detach

I'm trying to remove an area of my website with detach because I have on mind to use it again, this is what I coding in the HTML

```
<div id="container">
 <p>Hello</p> 
</div>
<div id="containerShow"></div>

<a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a> | <a href="#" id="show">Show</a>
```

and this is my Jquery

```
$("#remove").click(function(){   
   $("#container").detach();
});

$("#show").click(function(){   
   $("#container").detach().appendTo("#containerShow");
});
```

What is supposed to do is remove the div container when click the link "Remove" and bring back that same information when click the link "Show"
I know this look very simple, but the doc in jquery about detach is confused http://api.jquery.com/detach/ and I want a simple way to do it, I also found this post here [How to I undo .detach()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764254/how-to-i-undo-detach) but I don't make it work as I want.

My code remove my content fine, but I don't know how to get it back.
Any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to hold it somewhere, i.e. in a variable:

```
var element;

$("#remove").click(function(){   
   element = $("#container").detach(); // detach and store in variable
});

$("#show").click(function(){   
   element.appendTo("#containerShow"); // restore stored element
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You've already been given the answer to why you can't get your elements back using `detach`, but a simpler solution to the problem described in your example would be to use `hide` and `appendTo`:

```
$("#remove").click(function(){   
   $("#container").hide();
});
$("#show").click(function(){   
   $("#container").appendTo("#containerShow");
});
```

This works because [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) will move an element if it already exists in the DOM (which in this case it still does, because `hide` just hides it, rather than actually removing it). It also removes the need for the potentially global variable to store the detached element.

If `#containerShow` is not doing anything except providing a place to put the content back, you could get rid of it and just use `show` instead:

```
$("#show").click(function(){   
   $("#container").show();
});
```